# How to see all form validation error messages in a sweetalert instead of message "please fill out this field" - Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a form with input fields some of them required and others not required

i want to custom all validation error msgs that happened when before submitting the form

and display them in a sweetalert message

here is code:

```
<form action="{{route('question.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="unicode">        
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label class="master_label mandatory">الاسم </label>
        <input class="master_input" type="text" required name="user_name" id="user_name"  >    
    </div> 
<div class="col-xs-12 text-left">
    <button class="btn-2 save-btn bgcolor--sec"  id="save_btn" type="submit">save</button>
</div>
```

when submitting the form i got the following default message if field "user_name" is blank

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Auwu6.png)

i want to see it in a sweetalert message

Comment: Have you studied sweetalert? If yes. than you can use your custom validation through javascript and show your own message in sweetalert. You have to remove HTML5 attribute required then.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `required` attribute of your input, and add some JQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    // Add an event listener on the #save_btn
    $("#save_btn").click(function(event) { 

      //  Check if the input trimed value is null
      if (("#user_name").val().trim() === "") {

        // Prevent the form to be submited
        event.preventDefault(); 

        // And just fire the alert
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Error!',
            text: 'Your name is required !',
            icon: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'Ok!'
          })
      }

    }); 
});
```